# Wordpress pagination with custom post not counting correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm using the [WP-PageNavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) plugin to paginate my news area. It's not quite working as intended.

I have a total of 6 news items published, but I've offset it by 1 so it doesn't show the latest. With the pagination it's showing the same 5 news items on page 1 and 2. I've set the posts per page to be 5 so it shouldn't even be showing the page 2 link. The url does however change to page1 and page2.

There's probably something stupid I've done wrong!

```
<?php $portfolioloop = new WP_Query( array( 'paged' => get_query_var('paged'), 'post_type' => 'blog', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'sort_order' => 'DESC', 'offset' => 1)); ?>
<?php while ( $portfolioloop->have_posts() ) : $portfolioloop->the_post(); ?>

<div class="blog-item"> <img width="163" src="<?php echo the_field('image'); ?>" alt="<?php echo the_title(); ?>" />
  <div class="news-item">
    <p><?php echo the_time('F j, Y'); ?></p>
    <h2><?php echo the_title(); ?></h2>
    <p>
      <?php $content = get_the_content();
        if(strlen($content) > 120 ){     
            echo substr($content,0,120) . "..."; 
        }else{
            echo substr($content,0,120); 
        } ?>
      <br />
      <a class="read-more" href="<?php echo get_page_link($post->ID) ?>">Read more...</a> </p>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop.  ?>
<p class="news-page"><?php echo wp_count_posts('blog')->publish; ?> news items</p>
<?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $portfolioloop ) ); } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)

**Pagination Parameters**

- offset (int) - number of post to displace or pass over. Note: Setting offset parameter will ignore the paged parameter.

Do a test to see if you're on page one and use the offset, otherwise, don't set it.

Comment: Aha! That worked! Is there no way around the offset problem? Further up the page I'm showing the latest post in a more prominent way. In the loop in my question I don't want to show the latest post, therefore I needed the offset.

Comment: I think the best way would be to stick to using the offset parameter rather than paged. You can calculate how many to offset based on the page you're on. i.e. for page 2 you'd offset 6, page 3 offset 11 (page * posts-per-page - (posts-per-page -1 ) ). You might find a more elegant way than my pseudo ramblings here, but it should work.

Comment: Of course, you'll need to fiddle with the pagenavi parameters (keep offset at 1 in all cases) to get the page links correctly.